# Not able to achieve 10Gbe against one device

Tags: networking, nas, switch, 10gbit, iperf3

I have 3 different 10Gbe devices on my network and 2 switches. Switch 1 has a MacMini M2 with a 10Gbe ethernet connected via RJ45. Switch 2 have a Custom NAS and a Ubiquiti NVR connected via SFP+. Switch 1 is connected to Switch 2 via SFP+. Testing using iperf3 I get:

- MacMini to NVR: ~9.30 Gb as expected
- NVR to NAS: ~9.30 Gb as expected
- NAS to NVR: ~9.30 Gb as expected
- MacMini to NAS: ~6 Gb
  but
- MacMini to NAS using -R (reverse): ~9.30 Gb as expected!

Any ideas what could be limiting my connection to the NAS if it is clear I can achieve expected speeds to other devices and the NAS can also achieve expected speeds? Also why is the issue only one way? Thanks

Comment: Check the specifications of the SFP+ module in question. Check the specifications of the fiber cable and the Ethernet cable

Comment: What happens if you reverse the MacMini to NAS test? (`iperf -R`)

Comment: @Attie That's interesting, doing reverse I get full speed (~9.40Gb)! So the issue is one way only?!

Comment: I had to do some performance tuning to get my linux gear to run 10g at all https://superuser.com/questions/1808516/figuring-out-the-appropriate-tcp-window-size-in-ubuntu-and-how-would-i-know-h . Worth a look. Also might be helpful to mention what your custom nat runs.

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess its a settings issue. 10G support is a little finicky - and I got very similar speeds *to* a ubuntu box set up for 10G since the TCP windows are not optimised for 10G speeds.

They're sensible defaults for a decade or more ago, but you are going to be a little more generous with resources.

I'd guess since the NVR and MacMini both have 'native' 10G (and windows drivers are provided by the OEM), they've got things appropriately set up.

On ubuntu - and likely most other linux distributions you need to add the following lines to  `/etc/sysctl.conf`

```
net.core.wmem_max=4194304
net.core.rmem_max=12582912
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 87380 4194304
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 87380 4194304
```

In theory running `sysctl -p` should load these settings immediately but I rebooted. T[here's a good explanation of why it works, and my own research here](https://superuser.com/a/1808574/10165)

This will theoretically take up more system memory, but modern machines have a ton of memory anyway.

You will also want to turn on jumbo frames everywhere to get a little more performance. I've benchmarked up to 9.9 with these settings.